# Currency Converter not working properly - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, currency, converters

I'm new with JavaScript so please bear this in mind... I am trying to learn it by myself. I am working on a Currency Converter with custom exchange rates - no APIs.

I have managed to find a solution to the actual conversion, although it only works for the first output.
For example, if I want to convert 10 EUR to GBP it works.
The problem starts when I want to convert that 10 EUR to any other currency in the list, for example USD.
As you may notice, the first output currency is GBP on the list. My conversion works only for that one.
It doesn't work for any of the other currencies - so if I want to convert from EUR to CAD, it doesn't work. I would like to be able to convert from any currency to any currency available in the dropdown menus.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my HTML/Bootstrap:

```js
function Currency() {
  y = document.getElementById("converter").value;
  return y;
}

function Calculate() {
  y = Currency();

  x = document.getElementById("value1").value;

  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("value2").value = "";
  } else {
    switch (y) {
      case "EUR":
        document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 1;
        break;

      case "CAD":
        document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 3;
        break;

      case "CHF":
        document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 4;
        break;

      case "GBP":
        document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 5;
        break;

      case "USD":
        document.getElementById("value2").value = x * 6;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<h1>Currency Converter</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
    <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1">
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
    <select onchange="Currency(); Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter">
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
      <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
      <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row row-two">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2">
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
    <select onchange="Currency(); Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter">
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
      <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate the help in the matter - thank you so much!

Comment: First thing to learn: variables should be **declared** with `let` or `const`, as appropriate.

Comment: "not working properly" Can you explain in detail what is not working properly? What are you expecting? What is actually happening?

Comment: Hi @phuzi, I did explain the problem but I'll happily do it again: The conversion doesn't work completely. I have managed to find a solution to the actual conversion, although it only works for the first output. For example, if I want to convert 10 EUR to GBP it works. The problem starts when I want to convert that 10 EUR to any other currency in the list, for example USD.

Comment: Also "id" attribute values must be **unique** across an HTML page. You have two elements with id "converter", and that is not valid.

Comment: "The problem starts when I want to convert that 10 EUR to any other currency in the list, for example USD" is very vague. What problem do you encounter?

Comment: Thank you @Pointy for the feedback - corrected!

Comment: @phuzi Apologies for not being able to explain properly - I'll try again. My conversion works with from EUR to GBP, but not from EUR to USD or EUR to CAD etc. It only works with the first currency on the list - GBP. I'm so confused...

Comment: I have updated the question explaining a bit more the issue. The thing is, it's difficult to explain, I can't find the right words. So sorry...

Comment: `onchange="Currency(); Calculate()"` <-- calling Currency there is useless

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand how HTML and JS interconnect with each other. All HTML IDs must be unique. Here you have used `id="converter"` twice which is a violation of that rule. I  had to be unique in a single page and therefore there can be only one element with the ID `converter`. Let's rewrite the HTML first.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row row-two">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter2">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now come to the JS part. It's not best practice to throw variables without declaring them first.

Bad practice:

```
x = 10;
console.log(x)
```

Good Practice:

```
const x = 10;
let y = 5;
```

In JavaScript, you can declare a variable using `var`, `let`, and `const`. Use `const` when the declaration is final and the value won't be updated. If you think you will have to change the value of a variable in the future, use `let` instead of `const`.

Now, let's focus on the problem. In order to develop a currency converter, we need to retrieve the input value (1,2,3, etc.), input currency (i.e. EURO), and output currency (GBP). We can use `document.getElementById` for that.

```
function Calculate() {
    const input_currency = document.getElementById("converter").value;
  const output_currency = document.getElementById("converter2").value;
  
  const  inputElement = document.getElementById("value1");
  const  outputElement = document.getElementById("value2");
  
  const input = parseFloat(inputElement.value)
  let output = "";
    
}
```

Here, `input_currency` will be the currency from which the value will be converted to `output_currency`. `inputElement` is the first text field element and `outputElement` is the text field on which we will push our calculated output.

Notice that we have used a function name `parseFloat`. `parseFloat` converts any string to a floating-point number. By default, the value we gets from text field is a string, but since we are planning on performing mathematical operations, we need to cast them to number.

```
// output 4.5 as a number
console.log( parseFloat("4.5") )
```

Now let's apply some condition and calculate our value and store it inside `output` variable.

```
function Calculate() {
    const input_currency = document.getElementById("converter").value;
  const output_currency = document.getElementById("converter2").value;
  
  const  inputElement = document.getElementById("value1");
  const  outputElement = document.getElementById("value2");
  
  const input = parseFloat(inputElement.value)
  let output = "";
    
  switch (input_currency){
    case "EUR":
        
      if (output_currency == "GBP"){
      
        // EUR to GBP
        output = input * 0.86
        
      } else if (output_currency == "CAD"){
      
        // EUR to CAD
        output = input * 1.49
        
      } 
      ///... rest of the conversion
      
    break;
    
    // .... rest of the cases
  }
  
  
  outputElement.value = output;
  
}
```

All in together.

```js
function Calculate() {
    const input_currency = document.getElementById("converter").value;
  const output_currency = document.getElementById("converter2").value;
  
  const  inputElement = document.getElementById("value1");
  const  outputElement = document.getElementById("value2");
  
  const input = parseFloat(inputElement.value)
  let output = "";
    
  switch (input_currency){
    case "EUR":
        
      if (output_currency == "GBP"){
      
        // EUR to GBP
        output = input * 0.86
        
      } else if (output_currency == "CAD"){
      
        // EUR to CAD
        output = input * 1.49
        
      } 
      ///... rest of the conversion
      
    break;
    
    // .... rest of the cases
  }
  
  
  outputElement.value = output;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row row-two">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="converter2">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Both yours and @phuzi's works great. I understood a bit more! :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the duplicated IDs. You should change both instances of `convertor` to `currencyFrom` and `currencyTo`. This will let you identify the correct drop down.

```js
function Currency() {
  y = document.getElementById("currencyTo").value;
  return y;
}

function Calculate() {
  var currencyTo = Currency();

  var fromValue = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById("value2");

  if (value1 == "") {
    value2.value = "";
    return;
  }

  switch (y) {
    case "EUR":
      value2.value = fromValue * 1;
      break;

    case "CAD":
      value2.value = fromValue * 3;
      break;

    case "CHF":
      value2.value = fromValue * 4;
      break;

    case "GBP":
      value2.value = fromValue * 5;
      break;

    case "USD":
      value2.value = fromValue * 6;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="currencyFrom">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row row-two">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="currencyTo">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This will properly convert the value from `value1` to `value2` using the appropriate multiplier.

Unfortunately to do proper conversions you need to identify both the currency you're converting from and the currency you're converting to. Which requires a proper map between each combination of currencies.

The easiest way to do this is convert all input currencies to a particular curremcy and then convert that to the target:

```js
const eurCurrencyMap = {
  EUR: 1,
  CAD: 3,
  CHF: 4,
  GBP: 5,
  USD: 6
};

function Calculate() {

  var currencyFrom = document.getElementById('currencyFrom').value;
  var currencyTo = document.getElementById('currencyTo').value;
  var fromValue = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  var value2 = document.getElementById("value2");
  
  // check for empty input
  if (typeof(fromValue) !== "number"){
    value2.value = "";
    return;
  }
  
  // Convert value to Euros
  var inEuros = fromValue / eurCurrencyMap[currencyFrom];

  // Convert to target currency
  value2.value = inEuros * eurCurrencyMap[currencyTo];
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" oninput="Calculate()" class="form-control" id="value1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="currencyFrom">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row row-two">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-4">
      <select onchange="Calculate()" class="form-select" id="currencyTo">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @phuzi! Both yours and @lftieaq work great. I understood a bit more. So happy it works!